# what is wrong with this jquery delegate code?

Tags: jquery, function, delegates, undefined, ready

```
function onBodyLoad()
{       
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    //for testing in safari only, comment out for deploy to iphone with phonegap
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        loadPage('mainmenu', 'Home');

        $('#menus').toggle(); 

        //I have a nested div in this index.html file with id=menubottbutt  
        $("div").delegate("#menubottbutt","click",toggleMenu());

                $("div").delegate(".menuitem","click",toggleMenu());
    });


}
```

In the body element I have this

When this runs and I hit the delegate line I get the error **** 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating'$("div").delegate("#menubottbutt","click",toggleMenu())')

---

And of course I have the method toggleMenu defined above and it works when called from elsewhere.  It looks like this `function toggleMenu() {

```
$('#menus').toggle('slow'); 

$('#menubottbutt').toggleClass('pressed');
```

}
`

### Thanks

PS  this is what i have so far:
in my onBodyLoad I will use $("#menubottbutt").click(function(){toggleMenu();});
and elsewhere at opportune places I will call:
 $(".menuitem").click(function(){toggleMenu();});
this seems to address my issues but it would probably be better if i could get delegate to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 $("div").delegate("#menubottbutt","click",function(){toggleMenu();});
 $("div").delegate(".menuitem","click",function(){toggleMenu();});
```

third parameter has to be function name

either is good

- "toogleMenu()"
- "toggleMenu"
- function(){toggleMenu();} // this one is recommended

Comment: Hi, That's exactly what I started with and it gives the same problem.  Same on all three methods.

Comment: eventually I just found a  way to avoid using the delegate function (add the click  handler in the response preocess function) and then discovered that I had been using an older version of jquery that didn't support delegate anyway... Doh!!!!

Answer (score 1):

sorry but I didn't get your problem.

while reading your code I guess that there are 3 divs on your page that should execute a specified method when a user clicks on one off them.

So my solution would be in html

```
<div id="menu" class="menu"></div>
<div id="2ndMenu" class="menu"></div>
<div id="3rdMenu" class="menu"></div>
```

the JS would look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu').click(function(){toggleMenu()});
});
```

Hope that's what you're lookin for

Thorsten

Comment: thanks,i had tried something like that already but your code seems to work.  But isn't the delegate method better as this way any new .menuitem elements added won't automatically get the handler.

Comment: yup, my .menuitem divs do not get their handlers this way.

Comment: what do you mean by the term handler? You could also wire the toggleMenu method to the DOM elements by using the bind method. I haven't used the delegate method jet.